# How to bind TextBlock to self-made FrameworkElement property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a 'GameControl : FrameworkElement'. I have it in the xaml like this:

```
<local:GameControl x:Name="control"/>
```

This GameControl has a property that is an own class:

```
public Gem selectedGem {get; set;}
```

Now, I want to write this Gem's information into a TextBlock, so that the player will see its properties.

**How do I bind my own FrameworkElement's properties to the MainWindow's elements?**

--

Full xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="GemTowerDefense.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GemTowerDefense"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Gem Tower Defense" Height="670" Width="800"
    ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Grid>
    <Border Background="Gray" Height="600" Width="600" Margin="3,26,189,3">
        <local:GameControl x:Name="control"/>
    </Border>

    <Border Background="LightSlateGray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="285" Margin="608,181,0,0" Width="170">
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbInfo" Text="Gem information">
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

(Instead of Text=Gem Information, I want the binding to the control's selectedGem, or to one of its string type property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make your property a [dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview) and when binding that property to the TextBlock.Text, use a converter. Search Stackoverflow to find billion examples on both topics. The binding would look something like this:

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=control, Mode=OneWay, Path=selectedGem, Converter={local:ExampleConverter}}"
```

I find it easiest to create converter in code-behind:

```
public class ExampleConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public ExampleConverter()
    {

    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value != null && value is Gem)
            return (value as Gem).GemAsText();
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: TYVM! I have indeed looked at many solutions, but what all of them skipped was the part: Binding ElementName=control, which I did not know existed, I have only used it with DataContext and Path and as Static Resource. This solved my problem complitely.